# change leaflet icon or add an circle "on the fly"

Tags: javascript, leaflet

for our ham-radio project I've created a "livemap" that shows our repeaters, hotspot and so on. this works very good. the next step is to enhanced the map with mqtt, then we can "live" show if a repeater is speaking or not. mosquitto and paho-mqtt are also working here fine.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid', { closePopupOnClick: true, tap: false}).setView(
[51, 13],
        7
      )
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mymap)
     
    var repeatericon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://www.lausitzlink.de/repeatermap/images/relais.png',
        iconSize: [35]
    });
    var simplexicon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://www.lausitzlink.de/repeatermap/images/simplex.png',
        iconSize: [35]
    });
    var hotspoticon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://www.lausitzlink.de/repeatermap/images/hotspot.png',
        iconSize: [35]
    });
    var ownicon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://www.lausitzlink.de/repeatermap/images/own.png',
        iconSize: [35]
    });

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport({
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
    showCoverageOnHover: false,
    zoomToBoundsOnClick: true,
    maxClusterRadius: 30
});

var RepeaterLayer = L.layerGroup();
var SimplexLayer = L.layerGroup();
var HotspotLayer = L.layerGroup();


var overlays = {
"Relais": RepeaterLayer,
"Simplex": SimplexLayer,
"Hotspot": HotspotLayer
};

    var layersControl = L.control.layers(null, overlays);
     //layersControl.setPosition("bottomleft");
     layersControl.addTo(mymap);

mymap.addLayer(RepeaterLayer);
mymap.addLayer(SimplexLayer);
mymap.addLayer(HotspotLayer);

var marker = L.marker([51.63804, 14.040286],  {
 icon: repeatericon,
 title: 'DB0AF',
 alt: 'DB0AF',
}).addTo(RepeaterLayer)
                  
var popup = marker.bindPopup(
 Some Infos about the Repeater
)

markers.addLayer(marker)

var marker = L.marker([51.52781, 13.831336],  {
 icon: repeatericon,
 title: 'DB0LS',
 alt: 'DB0LS',
}).addTo(RepeaterLayer)
                  
var popup = marker.bindPopup(
 Some Infos about the Repeater
)
        
markers.addLayer(marker)

mymap.addLayer(markers)
```

the goal is, every time when mqtt message is arrived to modify an existing marker like with a circle or let the icon blinking. the function when mqtt message arrived, already exist:

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  alert(message.payloadString);
}
```

for testing reasons, a popup are shown if a message arrived. that works good.

I've created a css class "blinking" and try to modify the marker with:

`L.DomUtil.addClass(marker._icon, 'className');`

but I don't know how I can assign an existing marker

is it possible to assign an existing marker and change the icon or add an circle? can I give an ID to an marker to assign them?

thank you very much!

Comment: According to the docs the `ICON` assigned to the marker can have a `className` defined as option. See docs: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon

Comment: allright - but i have only 4 types of icons, if i assign a class to a icon, all repeaters with the same icon will blink. in this case i want blink or add a circle to one specific marker.

Answer (score 0):

now i'am a litte bit further to my goal. i've change the marker names directly to the repeater callsign, like this:

```
var DB0AF = L.marker([51.63804, 14.040286],  {
 icon: repeatericon,
 title: 'DB0AF',
 alt: 'DB0AF',
}).addTo(RepeaterLayer)
                
var popup = DB0AF.bindPopup(
    some infos here....             
)
markers.addLayer(DB0AF)
```

also i have created a css class "pulse" that can flash the icons.

here is my function, when mqtt messages arrives:

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {
        msg = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
        var callsign = msg['callsign'];
        
        alert(callsign)
        
         /* this works: 
            DB0AF._icon.classList.add("pulse"); 
            DB0AF.setIcon(simplexicon);*/
        
        /*if(msg['mode'] == "start") {
            L.DomUtil.addClass(callsign._icon, 'pulse'); 
        } else if (msg['mode'] == "stop") {
            L.DomUtil.removeClass(callsign._icon, 'pulse'); 
        }*/
    }
```

the `alert(callsign)` shows me the correct callsign if a mqtt arrived, this works good.

now the NOOB question:

when i write the marker name (in my case the repeater callsign) directly in the function, like:

```
DB0AF._icon.classList.add("pulse"); 
DB0AF.setIcon(simplexicon);
```

can i set sucessfull the new class or change the icon for testing porposes. this works not with the created javascript variable 'callsign'. how can i assign the callsign variable to use them with "classList.add" like this:

```
callsign._icon.classList.add("pulse");
```

or

```
L.DomUtil.addClass(callsign._icon, 'pulse');
```

thank you very much!